# \vspace behaving elastic in scrbook

Tags: koma-script, minipage

In the following minimal example, I want to have three paragraphs. Paragraphs should be ...

- Spaced 1 cm apart each other OR
- Pushed to the next page, if the don't fit entirely on the present page

I implemented this using minipages.

The following code works beautifully for `scrreport`, but in `scrbook` the second box will be pushed towards the bottom of the page.

```
\documentclass[DIV12]{scrreprt} % try 'scrbook' here

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\newcommand{\foo}{
  \vspace{1cm}
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \textbf{A box}
    \lipsum[1-2]
  \end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}

\foo

\foo

\foo

\end{document}
```

*Questions:*

- Why does that happen?
- Can it be overcome in `scrbook` or do you have a better suggestion than minipages for my purpose?

Comment: Did you mean `\vspace*` instead of `\vspace`?  The former, at the beginning of a paragraph, has no effect.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes No, that's intended. I don't want pages to space away from the page header, but just if there's something preceeding.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `\vspace*` only differs from `\vspace` at start of a _page_ not start of a _paragraph_.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, that shows how little I know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most `book` classes default to `\flushbottom` and so try to pull the text to the bottom of the page. You can add `\raggedbottom` to get the same behaviour as in report classes where the page is allowed to be short.

Comment: Is there a something like `\thispageraggedbottom` ?

Comment: @arney not exactly but you can switch between `\raggedbottom` aand `\flushbottom` within the document, just needs a bit of care where they go relative to page breaks